# Unable to withdraw funds from NFT contract

Tags: nft, error, tenderly

I am unable to withdraw funds from my NFT contract, appreciate your help, I am not a dev myself and the dev team could not help so far, here is the link to the error:

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/759f567a-8980-40d4-8fff-ebf8f0922182

Here are my input parameters:

```js
{
  "to": "0x7c844c610165ed8398f9e8faf3326434992eacc0",
  "value": "1000000000000000000",
  "data": "0x3ccfd60b",
  "operation": 0,
  "safeTxGas": "0",
  "baseGas": "0",
  "gasPrice": "0",
  "gasToken": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "refundReceiver": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "signatures": "0x00000000000000000000000010d0a0185ca52bab684d6b2404051532d0a68c74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
}
```

Here is my error message:

`Error Message: GS013`

Here is the exact line that is reverting:

```js
 require(success || safeTxGas != 0 || gasPrice != 0, "GS013");
```

Here is the entire function that is failing:

```js
/// @dev Allows to execute a Safe transaction confirmed by required number of owners and then pays the account that submitted the transaction.
    ///      Note: The fees are always transferred, even if the user transaction fails.
    /// @param to Destination address of Safe transaction.
    /// @param value Ether value of Safe transaction.
    /// @param data Data payload of Safe transaction.
    /// @param operation Operation type of Safe transaction.
    /// @param safeTxGas Gas that should be used for the Safe transaction.
    /// @param baseGas Gas costs that are independent of the transaction execution(e.g. base transaction fee, signature check, payment of the refund)
    /// @param gasPrice Gas price that should be used for the payment calculation.
    /// @param gasToken Token address (or 0 if ETH) that is used for the payment.
    /// @param refundReceiver Address of receiver of gas payment (or 0 if tx.origin).
    /// @param signatures Packed signature data ({bytes32 r}{bytes32 s}{uint8 v})
    function execTransaction(
        address to,
        uint256 value,
        bytes calldata data,
        Enum.Operation operation,
        uint256 safeTxGas,
        uint256 baseGas,
        uint256 gasPrice,
        address gasToken,
        address payable refundReceiver,
        bytes memory signatures
    ) public payable virtual returns (bool success) {
        bytes32 txHash;
        // Use scope here to limit variable lifetime and prevent `stack too deep` errors
        {
            bytes memory txHashData =
                encodeTransactionData(
                    // Transaction info
                    to,
                    value,
                    data,
                    operation,
                    safeTxGas,
                    // Payment info
                    baseGas,
                    gasPrice,
                    gasToken,
                    refundReceiver,
                    // Signature info
                    nonce
                );
            // Increase nonce and execute transaction.
            nonce++;
            txHash = keccak256(txHashData);
            checkSignatures(txHash, txHashData, signatures);
        }
        address guard = getGuard();
        {
            if (guard != address(0)) {
                Guard(guard).checkTransaction(
                    // Transaction info
                    to,
                    value,
                    data,
                    operation,
                    safeTxGas,
                    // Payment info
                    baseGas,
                    gasPrice,
                    gasToken,
                    refundReceiver,
                    // Signature info
                    signatures,
                    msg.sender
                );
            }
        }
        // We require some gas to emit the events (at least 2500) after the execution and some to perform code until the execution (500)
        // We also include the 1/64 in the check that is not send along with a call to counteract potential shortings because of EIP-150
        require(gasleft() >= ((safeTxGas * 64) / 63).max(safeTxGas + 2500) + 500, "GS010");
        // Use scope here to limit variable lifetime and prevent `stack too deep` errors
        {
            uint256 gasUsed = gasleft();
            // If the gasPrice is 0 we assume that nearly all available gas can be used (it is always more than safeTxGas)
            // We only substract 2500 (compared to the 3000 before) to ensure that the amount passed is still higher than safeTxGas
            success = execute(to, value, data, operation, gasPrice == 0 ? (gasleft() - 2500) : safeTxGas);
            gasUsed = gasUsed.sub(gasleft());
            // If no safeTxGas and no gasPrice was set (e.g. both are 0), then the internal tx is required to be successful
            // This makes it possible to use `estimateGas` without issues, as it searches for the minimum gas where the tx doesn't revert
            require(success || safeTxGas != 0 || gasPrice != 0, "GS013");
            // We transfer the calculated tx costs to the tx.origin to avoid sending it to intermediate contracts that have made calls
            uint256 payment = 0;
            if (gasPrice > 0) {
                payment = handlePayment(gasUsed, baseGas, gasPrice, gasToken, refundReceiver);
            }
            if (success) emit ExecutionSuccess(txHash, payment);
            else emit ExecutionFailure(txHash, payment);
        }
        {
            if (guard != address(0)) {
                Guard(guard).checkAfterExecution(txHash, success);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The call is reverting because the `execute()` function call is returning `false`, and the `safeTxGas` and `gasPrice` input param are both being passed as `0`.

Here is the `execute()` function call:

```js
success = execute(to, value, data, operation, gasPrice == 0 ? (gasleft() - 2500) : safeTxGas);
```

Here is the entire Execute contract, the only function in it is `execute()`:

```js
contract Executor {
    function execute(
        address to,
        uint256 value,
        bytes memory data,
        Enum.Operation operation,
        uint256 txGas
    ) internal returns (bool success) {
        if (operation == Enum.Operation.DelegateCall) {
            // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
            assembly {
                success := delegatecall(txGas, to, add(data, 0x20), mload(data), 0, 0)
            }
        } else {
            // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
            assembly {
                success := call(txGas, to, value, add(data, 0x20), mload(data), 0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

The error message shows the line that is reverting, and it is a conditional checking that either `success` is `true`, **OR** that `safeTxGas` is not `0`, **OR** that `gasPrice` is not `0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the issue was resolved, the issue was with Safe Wallet, when I was using its app the error was happening but once I tried using the Safe web UI, it all worked fine.
Also, I did use 0 amount for withdrawal, any other number would be failed.